# how should I describe my status in job applications? I have just passed my PhD oral defence

Tags: job-search, academic-life, degree, graduation

I have passed my PhD viva voce and submitted my revised thesis. Currently, I am waiting for my degree to be conferred which will take one to two months. How should I describe/introduce my academic status in cover letters when applying for jobs?

I have learnt a phrase "degree pending", not sure if it suits my case?

Comment: Is the rest purely administrative or are there still judgements to be made? Is the degree assured?

Comment: degree assured, just waiting for the conferral

Comment: The answer by Buzz seems right. At my university, when the committee completed it's deliberations after the defense, we invited the candidate back into the room and addressed her as "Dr. Elizabeth" or the equivalent. Congratulations Dr. Elizabeth.

Comment: yes, same in my uni. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just write:  "Ph.D. completed, to be awarded [month, year]."

Comment: I  have learnt a phrase "degree pending", not sure if it suits my case?

Comment: I think that "completed" makes it clearer than "pending". The latter is a bit "fuzzier".